# Paperclip S3 default_url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, paperclip

I am using s3 with Paperclip which is working well. I am running into problems however with the `default_url` for missing attachements. I want the `default_url` to be `:attachement/default/:style` in the same s3 bucket as the other files. However the `default_url` when used to generate a missing image is local for the rails app which is not what I want. E.g

`/avatar/default/thumb` is not what I want for the default, instead I want `{s3_base_url}/avatar/default/thumb`. I cannot figure out how to do this.

Comment: have you tried to replace the missing images using javascript? that can point to your s3 image url... check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92720/jquery-javascript-to-replace-broken-images

Comment: This is for a REST API so no javascript available. I solved it, but I am not really satisfied with the result. I'll post my answer though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I solved it, but I am not overly pleased with the solution.

**initializers/paperclip.rb**

`Paperclip.interpolates(:s3_bucket) do |attachement, style|
  Rails.application.config.paperclip_defaults[:s3_credentials][:bucket]
end`

**Model**

`default_url: "http://:s3_bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/avatar/default/:style`

It would of course be possible to add a fuller interpolation with the complete path to s3, but this is a workable solution.